# Adding tomatoes to pizza dough

Tags: pizza, tomatoes

I want to try this pizza recipe and it calls for putters beets to be added to the dough to make it red. Currently, I have so many tomatoes. Would replacing the beets with tomatoes affect the crust at all? The recipe is here: https://www.google.com/amp/s/tasty.co/recipe/rainbow-sheet-pan-pizza

Comment: You'd probably have better luck with tomato paste than with straight tomatoes. Sliced tomatoes makes a good pizza topping, though.

Answer (score 4):

I would guess that (a) the water content of tomatoes would be higher, for which you would have to compensate, and (b) they won't color your dough as dramatically as beetroot, but they might impact the flavor more.

Answer (score 1):

You could try sun-dried tomatoes? The kind not in oil.

Comment: In the past I've used the sun-dried tomatoes in oil. I replaced the olive oil I usually use with the oil from the sun-dried tomatoes and diced the tomatoes finely. The dough doesn't turn bright red but it does have a red hue to it with red dots from the tomatoes.

Comment: That's awesome! I was concerned about the oil in the tomatoes degrading the dough but if you have had success with it then I just might try it with the oil myself. I love the oil from the tomato jar. I always use it to cook with :) You could try a little bit of natural food coloring? I just thought of beet powder...